# PDF zoom level changes on every page

Tags: pdf, zoom

I downloaded a large .pdf for a class, and it works perfectly, except that every time I scroll to a new page the zoom level changes to 64.8% (fit to page). I zoom in to 100% so that I can actually read it, but new pages always force it to revert back to the fit to page option.

This happens in Adobe Acrobat, Adobe Reader, and Foxit Reader. I do have access to Acrobat X Pro if changes can be made in that program to fix the issue.

Comment: Normally you should be able to override the document's settings in the reader. Is it like a PDF slideshow? Perhaps you can try other apps to see if they can do better at remembering your preferences.

Answer (score 1):

Highlight the bookmark, right click, properties, actions tab, highlight "go to a page" in the actions window, click edit button just below window, change zoom to inherit zoom. Hit OK, OK. Downside is that you have to do this individually for each bookmark.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that in the initial view settings for the PDF the zoom is specified as fit page. When you manually change the zoom level while viewing a page this zoom level will be maintained so long as the page size is the same page size as the previous page. If the page size changes, then the zoom level reverts back to fit page.

In your case it sounds like there are a number of different page sizes used in the PDF and so the zoom level settings keep on changing to compensate.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Adobe Acrobat Pro, so I don't know what may be special to that software, but I was having this same issue and none of the suggestions (Accessibility, Page Display, Properties/Initial View) would fix it. Then I found the problem under the Bookmarks.  When I right-clicked on each item in the bookmark list, selected "properties" and then clicked on the "Actions" tab, I could edit the Zoom level for each Bookmark (where they were all set at the Zoom level that was driving me crazy).  I clicked on "Edit", changed the Zoom level, and then said "OK" (twice). I had to save the document to make sure it would retain the settings when I next opened the document. I think the issue was actually buried in a Java Script action that was overriding everything else - at least this is what worked for me. It was a pain because I had to make the change with every single bookmark, which in my case was many, but it fixed it so I can finally stop pulling out my hair.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).